# Pythonic way to do if statement comparisons only if the variable is not None

Tags: python, if-statement

Is there a more pythonic way to do this if block?

```
def is_notification_needed(request: RiverPreference, gauge: Gauge) -> bool:
    """
    Decides whether an email should be sent to the user or not based on their provided preferences.
    :param request: RiverPreference dataclass
    :param gauge: Gauge dataclass
    :returns: boolean
    """
    for preference in request:
        if preference.level and preference.trend and preference.level >= gauge.level and preference.trend == gauge.trend:
            return True
        elif preference.level and not preference.trend and preference.level >= gauge.level:
            return True
        elif preference.trend and not preference.level and preference.trend == gauge.level:
            return True
        return False
```

`preference.trend` and `preference.level` default to `None` when the user doesn't want to set it. I'd like to be able to check these values against the gauge values only if they are set.

Comment: Combine your conditions

Comment: I dont think there is something pythonic about that. Just plain use of boolean "and" and 
"or" operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, the pythonic way to compare would be `is not None`, which is important if your values can be falsy (`0`).

Second off, your indentation looks off, and there is a typo in logic, but I think your goal is to return True if all conditions for any preference are met, and False otherwise, this would be simpler by checking negatives.

```
    for preference in request:
        if preference.level is not None and preference.level < gauge.level:
            continue
        if preference.trend is not None and preference.trend != gauge.trend:
            continue
        return True  # NB: treats all-None as a match
    return False
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is more Pythonic, but I certainly find it easier to understand at a glance.

```py
def is_notification_needed(request: RiverPreference, gauge: Gauge) -> bool:
    """
    Decides whether an email should be sent to the user or not based on their provided preferences.
    :param request: RiverPreference dataclass
    :param gauge: Gauge dataclass
    :returns: boolean
    """
    preference = request[0]
    if preference.trend is None:
        if preference.level is None:
            return False
        return preference.trend >= gauge.level
    elif preference.level is None:
        return preference.trend == gauge.level
    return preference.level >= gauge.level and preference.trend == gauge.trend
```

The main principle here is to get rid of the `None` cases as early as possible, and then rely in the subsequent code on the fact that we know these values are defined.

If the values could be *falsey* for other reasons too, probably change the `is None` to something less specific.

Comment: After this I deleted my answer. Your logic to get rid of the None cases as early as possible is much better than combining conditions.

Answer (score 0):

First, it’s better to explicitly compare with `None`, instead of “abusing” the boolean value of `None`. Remember *“explicit is better than implicit”* from the Zen of Python ([PEP-20](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)). That is,

```
if preference.level is not None and ...
```

is better than just

```
if preference.level and ...
```

On the other hand, you *can* make use of the fact that `None` has a boolean `False` value by doing this:

```
if (preference.level or 0) >= gauge.level:
```

instead of:

```
if preference.level and preference.level >= gauge.level:
```

Of course, you should specify an appropriate value instead of `0` (depending on what values `gauge.level` can have); this is just an example.

Using the `or` operator to provide a default value for a variable that can be `None` (or `False`, or any other boolean False equivalent) is actually used quite often in Python programs, and I would call this a “Pythonic” way to express this.

By the way, your `for` loop is meaningless, because your loop body always returns on the first pass through the loop.

Answer (score 0):

There are many logically equivalent ways to do this, but my preference in this case would be to invert the logic and try to figure out when you need to return `False`, because we now have no more than one `and` or `or` per condition, which makes a large difference to how easy to maintain code is in my experience.

(I assume `RiverPreference` works as a sequence of `preference` objects?)

```
def is_notification_needed(request: RiverPreference, gauge: Gauge) -> bool:
    """
    Decides whether an email should be sent to the user or not based on their provided preferences.
    :param request: RiverPreference dataclass
    :param gauge: Gauge dataclass
    :returns: boolean
    """
    preference = request[0]
    if preference.level and preference.level < gauge.level:
         return False
    if preference.trend and preference.trend != gauge.level:
         return False
    return preference.level or preference.trend
```

(You may need to add `is None` to the checks for `preference.level` and `preference.trend` if `0` or `0.0` can be a valid value for the gauge levels.)